# Implementing DataSource in Java to connect to my database

Tags: java, database, oracle, connection, datasource

I'm trying to write a class that implements DataSource. This seems simple enough, but the examples I'm seeing for Oracle all declare the class like this:

```
public class ConnectionPoolingBean implements SessionBean {
    ....
}
```

I would expect to see something more like this:

```
public class MyDataSource implements DataSource {
    ....
}
```

Also, I don't understand how the connection is actually working. The getConnection() method only takes the arguments for username and password. So how am I connecting to my database?
Ultimately, what I need to understand is how do I connect to my database and return a result set from a query using DataSource.  I just don't see any clear examples of how write a class to use this on my WebApp.

Here's what I've been reading from, which is now just confusing me.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqldatasources.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html

Comment: You're not supposed to implement a DataSource yourself. Your database driver is supposed to provide one (or your connection pooling library)

Answer (score 1):

Use any connection pool for your use case.If you are using app server you can use app server connection pool or use opensource dbcp connection pool mechanism.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-dbcp/commons-dbcp -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Example

```
import org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource;


public class DataBaseUtility
{
    private static BasicDataSource dataSource;

    private static BasicDataSource getDataSource()
    {

        if (dataSource == null)
        {
            BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
            ds.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test");
            ds.setUsername("root");
            ds.setPassword("password");


            ds.setMinIdle(5);
            ds.setMaxIdle(10);
            ds.setMaxOpenPreparedStatements(100);

            dataSource = ds;
        }
        return dataSource;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException
    {

        try (BasicDataSource dataSource = DataBaseUtility.getDataSource(); 
                Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
                PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM account");)
        {
System.out.println("The Connection Object is of Class: "+connection.getClass());
            try (ResultSet resultSet = pstmt.executeQuery();)
            {
                while (resultSet.next())
                {
                    System.out.println(resultSet.getString(1) + "," + resultSet.getString(2) + "," + resultSet.getString(3));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                connection.rollback();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for posting this. I'm attempting to implement it. I'll post back and mark it as the answer once I get it going.